# Add description to Related Products

Tags: magento2, product, php, attributes, related-products

I try to add product **Short Description** in the **Related Products** section in Magento 2.4 version.

I overwrite this file:*/app/design/frontend/Theme/MyTheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml* in my custom theme and I add the following code:

```
<?=/* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($item, $item->getShortDescription(), 'short_description')?>
```

The code work only for Simple Products if there in the related products are some configurable products the code is not return anything.

Is there any way to have the short description for both types of products?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried  ```<?php echo $item->getDescription(); ?>``` also can you provide more code, or all the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to show short description.

```
<?php echo $item->getShortDescription(); ?>
```